# using awk to select lines in file A, based on finding matches in file B

Tags: awk

I have two files, file A looks like this:

```
1       101427      GENE|ACT-A      1       101589      GENE|ACT-B    0.0357
1       101427      GENE|ACT-A      1       101785      GENE|ACT-C    0.6357
1       101427      GENE|TAD-J      1       101437      GENE|TAD-L    0.8967
1       101427      GENE|TAD-J      1       158988      GENE|TAD-O    0.0067
1       101427      GENE|TAD-J      1       159999      GENE|TAD-V    0.5427
1       101427      GENE|POL-D      1       101437      GENE|POL-H    0.2347
```

and file B looks like this:

```
GENE|ACT-A
GENE|TAD-L
GENE|POL-D
```

I would like to select the lines in file A,  where either column 3 or column 6 have a match in file B. In the above example the output would look like:

```
1       101427      GENE|ACT-A      1       101589      GENE|ACT-B    0.0357
1       101427      GENE|ACT-A      1       101785      GENE|ACT-C    0.6357
1       101427      GENE|TAD-J      1       101437      GENE|TAD-L    0.8967
1       101427      GENE|POL-D      1       101437      GENE|POL-H    0.2347
```

Can this be achieved simply with some awk.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR == NR {keys[$1]; next} $3 in keys || $6 in keys' fileB fileA
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the awk solution as it only has to examine each file once, but here's an alternative.

```
{ join -1 3 <(sort -k3 fileA) <(sort fileB) 
  join -1 6 <(sort -k6 fileA) <(sort fileB)
} > output
```