# Comparing two text files and counting number of occurrences

Tags: shell, scripting, ssid

I'm trying to write a blog post about the dangers of having a common access point name.

So I did some wardriving to get a list of access point names, and I downloaded a list of the 1000 most common access point names (which there exists rainbow tables for) from Renderlab.

But how can I compare those two text files, to see how many of my collected access point names that are open to attacks from rainbow tables?

The text files are build like this:

collected.txt:

```
linksys
internet
hotspot
```

Most common access point names are called
SSID.txt:

```
default
NETGEAR
Wireless
WLAN
Belkin54g
```

So the script should sort the lines, compare them and show how many times the lines from collected.txt are found in SSID.txt ..

Does that make any sense? Any help would be grateful :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [using awk to select lines in file A, based on finding matches in file B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584531/using-awk-to-select-lines-in-file-a-based-on-finding-matches-in-file-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using python script:

```
file1=open('collected.txt', 'r')            # open file 1 for reading
with open('SSID.txt', 'r') as content_file: # ready file 2
    SSID = content_file.read()

found={}                                    # summary of found names
for line in file1:
    if line in SSID:
        if line not in found:
            found[line]=1
        else:
            found[line]+=1
for i in found:
    print found[i], i                       # print out list and no. of occurencies
```

...it can be run in the dir containing these files - collected.txt and SSID.txt - it will return a list looking like this:

```
5 NETGEAR
3 default
(...)
```

Script reads file 1 line-by line and compares it to the whole file 2. It can be easily modified to take file names from command prompt.

Comment: I don't mind using Python at all. But I can't get this script to run. It's in the same dir as collected.txt and SSID.txt, but when I execute it with "python compare.py" nothing happens. 
I run Python 2.7.5+. Any idea what might be wrong? :)

Comment: Awesome :)! 
I credited you on my post: http://nicknielsen.dk/blog/wardriving-with-kismet/

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look on a simple tutorial about sdiff command, like [How do I Compare two files under Linux or UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-compare-two-files-under-linux-or-unix/). Also, Notepad++ support this.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of times each line in file A appears in file B, you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1; next} $0 in a { count[$0]++ } 
    END { for( i in a ) print i, count[i] }' A B
```

If you want the output sorted, pipe the output to `sort`, but there's no need to sort just to find the counts.  Note that the `$0 in a` clause can be omitted at the cost of consuming more memory, which may be a problem if file B is very large.