# in unix :how do i print all the lines of file 1 which contain the words of file 2

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

example :

File1 :

```
AA123|1111|111
BB123|2222|222
CC123|3333|333
DD123|4444|444
```

File2:

```
CC123
AA123
```

required output :

```
CC123|3333|333
AA123|1111|111
```

Comment: There are countless examples of how to do this kind of thing already on this site.

Comment: Please clarify your question. How do you define a *word*? Can the match be anywhere? Do your pipe symbols have any significance?

Comment: Possible duplicate :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686690/comparing-two-text-files-and-counting-number-of-occurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the modified question, the answer can be easier,

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1 in a)' file2 file1
AA123|1111|111
CC123|3333|333
```

Brief explanations,

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]`: save `$1` in file2 as the keys of the array
- `($1 in a)`: print the line in file1 if `$1` matched to the key in the array

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for the notification, I have modified my answer.

Comment: @abhinavbharadwaj You may check the answer as accepted if it does help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Plain grep can do this:

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

We could get more precise and add the -F and -w options.

Answer (score 0):

awk scriptfile:

```
FNR == 1 && FNR != NR {
                         strt=1
                      }
strt != 1 {
                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                                cnt++;fnd[cnt]=$i
                                }
          }
strt==1 {
                for (p=1;p<=cnt;p++) {
                                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                                        if ($i ~ fnd[p] ) {
                                                printf ("%s ",$i)
                                        }
                                }
                }
        }
```

Call the scriptfile with:

```
awk -f scriptfile File2 File1
```

We process both files at the same time. Reading the data in File2 into an array first and then using this to loop through each field in File1 printing the matches to the array (fnd) separated by spaces.

This will print a continuous line of text with line feeds (I'm not sure how you want to deal with that)

Comment: Thanks you ,
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1 in a)' file2 file1
this has worked best for me