# Comparing two files in Unix and remove the contents of one file that are not present

Tags: unix, awk

Say for example I have 2 files.

File1

```
1,Unix,100
2,Java,200
3,c++,300
```

File2

```
Unix
c++
```

**Desired output**

```
1,Unix,100
3,c++,300
```

I am trying using the awk statement with the FNR variables but I am unable to get the output.

Thanks in advance.
Tahir

Comment: `grep -f file2 file1` ..... this question is duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [using awk to select lines in file A, based on finding matches in file B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584531/using-awk-to-select-lines-in-file-a-based-on-finding-matches-in-file-b)

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM, using grep may get false positives if the strings from file2 appear elsewhere in file1. We don't know the complete set of input data.

Comment: @ghoti It's concurrent question ..... I understand, grep can generate false positives .....

Comment: * recurrent instead of concurrent ;P

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next; } $2 in a' file2 file1
```

The idea here is that you load up your array with the exclusions from the first file specified (file2), then step through the main data printing only lines that have an array element present in field 2.